# Add vertically-aligned text between two enumerate items

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, enumerate, enumitem, vertical

I'd like to get something like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item $Y^2 - 1 = 0$ \quad (text)
  \item $Y^2 + 1 = 0$ \quad (text) 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a simple `\raisebox`, wrapped in a macro taking into account `\itemsep` and `\parsep` values (thanks to circumscribe, I have change to `\glueexpr`, since all involved lengths are glues, not ordinary lengths!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\raisecontent}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\glueexpr\baselineskip/2+\parsep/2+\itemsep/2+\lineskip/2}[\ht\strutbox][\ht\strutbox]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item $Y^2 - 1 = 0$ 
  \item $Y^2 + 1 = 0$ \raisecontent{\quad (text)}
 \end{enumerate}

 \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=40pt]
  \item $Y^2 - 1 = 0$ 
  \item $Y^2 + 1 = 0$ \raisecontent{\quad (text)}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Working in progress...

Comment: @Circumscribe: Thanks, I totally forgot about `\glueexpr`....

Comment: @Circumscribe: I changed and apparently the slight vertical shift is removed. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89475/discussion-between-circumscribe-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: @Circumscribe: Oh, I thought `\itemsep` etc. would be normal length 'registers' and skip's'

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, based on `tabularx` and `listliketab`, which emulates list environments within tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, listliketab, multirow}

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\addtocounter{tabenum}{1}\thetabenum.}
 \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L l@{\quad}X@{}}
  \tabitem & $Y^2 - 1 = 0$ & \multirow{2}{=}{(Text)}\\
  \tabitem & $Y^2 + 1 = 0$
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]